# Check file exist on UploadiFive

Tags: php, file, upload, uploadify

I downloaded this upload example: https://github.com/xmissra/UploadiFive

When sending an apernas file, it works perfectly but when sending more than one file the function that checks if the file already exists presents a problem. Apparently the loop does not ignore that the file has just been sent and presents the message asking to replace the file. Is there any way to solve this?

This is the function that checks if the file already exists.

```
$targetFolder = 'uploads'; // Relative to the root and should match the upload folder in the uploader 
script

if (file_exists($targetFolder . '/' . $_POST['filename'])) {
    echo 1;
} else {
    echo 0;
}
```

You can test the upload working at: http://inside.epizy.com/index.php

*Submit a file and then send more than one to test.

I tried it this way but it didn't work:

```
$targetFolder = 'uploads';

$files = array($_POST['filename']);

foreach($files as $file){
if (file_exists($targetFolder . '/' . $file)) {
    echo 1;
} else {
    echo 0;
}
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20597285/using-uploadifive-for-multiple-file-upload-causes-repeated-invocations-of-check

Answer (score 0):

When you have multiple files to be uploaded keep these things in mind;

**HTML**

1. Input name must be array `name="file[]"`
2. Include `multiple` keyword inside input tag.

eg; `<input name="files[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />`

**PHP**

1. Use syntax `$_FILES['inputName']['parameter'][index]`
2. Look for empty files using `array_filter()`

   ```
   $filesCount = count($_FILES['upload']['name']);

   // Loop through each file
   for ($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {

    // $files = array_filter($_FILES['upload']['name']); use if required 

   if (file_exists($targetFolder . '/' . $_FILES['upload']['name'][$i])) {
       echo 1;
   } else {
   echo 0;
   }
   }
   ```

Comment: I tried it this way but it didn't work: `$targetFolder = 'uploads';

$files = array($_POST['filename']);

foreach($files as $file){
if (file_exists($targetFolder . '/' . $file)) {
    echo 1;
} else {
    echo 0;
}`

Comment: Have you enabled multiple files in the input tag for your html . https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_multiple.asp

Comment: If you have used multiple in the input tag. You have to use $_FILES instead of $_POST for getting the file name.

Comment: It also didn't work this way `$files = array($_FILES['filename']);`

Comment: Its not the right way to use $_FILES : https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php

Comment: Hi Nithin Suresh, his example uploads but now he doesn't check if the file already exists. When sending a file with the same name, the script does not ask if you want to replace i